# How to read serialized data by python2 cPikle with python3 pickle?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, serialization, pickle

I'm trying to work with [CIFAR-10 dataset](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html) which contains [a special version for python](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz).

It is a set of binary files, each representing a dictionary of 10k numpy matrices. The files were obviously created by python2 `cPickle`.

I tried to load it from python2 as follows:

```
import cPickle
with open("data/data_batch_1", "rb") as f:
    data = cPickle.load(f)
```

This works really great. However, if I try to load the data from python3 (that hasn't `cPickle` but `pickle` instead), it fails:

```
import pickle
with open("data/data_batch_1", "rb") as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
```

If fails with the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Can I somehow transform the ofiginal dataset into new one that will be readable from python3? Or may I somehow read it from python3 direrctly?

I've tried loading it by `cPickle`, dumping it into `json` and reading it back by `pickle`, but numpy matrices obviously can't be written as a json file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to tell pickle what codec to use for those bytestrings, or tell it to load the data as `bytes` instead. From the [`pickle.load()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.load):

> The *encoding* and *errors* tell pickle how to decode 8-bit string instances pickled by Python 2; these default to ‘ASCII’ and ‘strict’, respectively. The *encoding* can be ‘bytes’ to read these 8-bit string instances as bytes objects.

To load the strings as `bytes` objects that'd be:

```
import pickle
with open("data/data_batch_1", "rb") as f:
    data = pickle.load(f, encoding='bytes')
```

Comment: Just for others who find this via google: if you apply this fix, then get a message `TypeError: must be a unicode character, not bytes`, your numpy version is too old and has [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4879) bug.

Comment: maybe better to use latin1 and not bytes

Comment: @ShimonDoodkin: that would depend entirely on the data. And just because Latin-1 always works doesn't mean you actually had Latin-1 data.